# tvOS searchController viewWillAppear not being called when navigating back

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, tvos, viewwillappear

So I followed the instructions for the recommended way of adding a search view controller. Basically

```
let resultsController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(SearchResultsViewController.storyboardIdentifier) as? SearchResultsViewController
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)

searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Enter keyword (e.g. iceland)", comment: "")               

let searchContainer = UISearchContainerViewController(searchController: searchController)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(searchContainer, animated: true)
```

And when it first loads the `viewWillAppear()` of my `resultsController` is called, but if I click a result and then press the menu button (to go back in the stack) `viewWillAppear()` isn't called again. Is there anyway to capture that appearance event?

Comment: I create a subclass of UISearchContainerViewController and viewWillAppear get called for subclass of  UISearchContainerViewController